# Wordpress author name coming twice

Tags: wordpress

I am using Wordpress to create a blog. I am showing author name in the article but it is repeating. I am using the get_the_author(); function

Here is my wordpress site: http://hideawayharbor.org/blog/

Comment: Could you please post the block code use are using?

Comment: yes it happens for me as well, VERY WEIRD.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

## Solutions

1. You might be accidently writing it twice?
2. If it shows twice in all the themes then there might be something attached to the author name hook and displaying it twice

Answer (score 11):

Write `get_the_author();` instead of `the_author();`

It will display single author.

Comment: Just to add to this, the reason is that `the_author()` returns the author **and** echoes it. So, when you echo `the_author()`, it is echoed once in the function, and once when you echo it.

Comment: I believe this is the real answer to this question! The one that's been chosen isn't a real solution... So, thanks for this answer! Cheers!

Comment: THis is the answer for me! Thanks @Bjjs JKD!

Answer (score 3):

It shows twice when you write

```
<?php echo the_author(); ?>
```

It will be

```
<?php the_author(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should open up /wp-content/themes/YOURTHEME/single.php in an editor (such as Dreamweaver)
and do a search on the string "Posted by"

Then check your code and you may find it's echo'ing it twice there.

You would also have to fix this in page.php, archive.php and possibly others.

Post the code you find here if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not 
    echoing `the_author()`

Its either

```
the_author()
```

or

```
echo get_the_author()
```